# Cannot click on a hidden element, which becomes visible only after hovering over the parent element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There are 10 items. I need to click on the hidden element (item-icon) in the item_9. The hidden element appear after hovering on him. I have the same situation and the same code operate as expected. But in this situation code operate as unexpected and get Error in  the console.
How can I click on the item-icon element in the item_9 element?

html:

```
<div class="item">
 <div class="w">item_1</div>
  <div class="d">
    <div style="display:none" class="item-icon" role="button" tabindex="-1">
      button1
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" class="item-icon">
      button2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="w">item_2</div>
  <div class="d">...</div>
</div>
      ...

<div class=""><div class="item">
  <div class="w">item_10</div>
  <div class="d">...</div>
</div></div>
```

js:

```
let findItems = await driver.findElements(By.className("item"));
let items = findItems.map(async elem => await elem.getText());
let allItems = await Promise.all(items);
await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//div[@class='item'][9]//div[@class='item-icon'][2]`)).click();
```

Console Error:

```
{ NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='item'][9]//div[@class='item-icon'][2]"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using JavascriptExecutor to click on hidden elements.

Sample code in Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element exists, but you get the error 'NoSuchElementError', it means that the element you are trying to find in the code exists inside an 'iframe' tag in the webpage.
**e.g.**

```
<iframe id="iframeID">
<div class="item">
  <div class="w">item_2</div>
  <div class="d">...</div>
</div>
      ...
</iframe>
```

What you need to do is to switch to that iframe, then find the element with class name "item".

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeNameOrID"); //you can use name or id for that iframe
//OR driver.switchTo().frame(0); the zero is the first iframe, you can use 1 for 2nd and so on...
let findItems = await driver.findElements(By.className("item"));
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); //switch back to the main webpage
//...
```

I assume that you have seen the code before hovering over it, and the code given by you is also valid if you don't hover over the element. I am answering according to the provided data :-)

**IF THERE IS NO IFRAME...**
**Hover using selenium**

Start the page and without hovering, use Chrome DevTools to select that area which should be hovered. This will show you the element which you need to hover. You can perform a element.click() on that element, which will then execute the java script to create your desired element "item".

I hope this will help... Leave questions in the comments :-)